# favorite tips for using screen(1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, gnu-screen

I've been meaning to learn screen for a long time, but have never gotten around to it.

What are you favorite tips?

Please try to keep one tip per answer so that we can vote properly, but feel free to answer multiple times.

Reference:
    http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/

Answer (score 2):

Among using split / vertical split or byobu for obvious reasons, one of the things I had a problem with was sending ^s or ^q to some applications (e.g. rtorrent) within screen as these shortcut keys conflicted with others I have set (^q = close window).

One way to get around this is to hit ^aq to send ^q to a program running within screen.

Answer (score 2):

`screen -dr` will always reconnect for me. This is assuming just one screen session is running, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a great tip, but if you are an [emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) user, like me, maybe you'll find useful mimic its key bindings (at least for what concerns splitting windows), in my `~/.screenrc` I have:

```
escape ^xX

bind 2 split
bind 3 split -v
bind o focus
bind ^c quit
```

So, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> will split the region horizzontally.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen -R -DD <pid>
```

That will force screen to reconnect to the terminal session no matter what happens.

Comment: screen -rd will do the same without even needed the pid unless you have multiple screens running.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use Ubuntu Linux, so you could easily install [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu), a nice preconfigured `screen` variant.

Comment: I noticed that too. I tried it out and it's quite simple to use. I think I'll keep it.

Comment: or .. tmux.sf.net

Answer (score 1):

`screen -x [screen_session_name]` allows you to attach to a screen session that is already attached, for multiple displays and screen sharing.

I posted this as a separate answer so it can get separate votes. I assume that's how it's done.